# v-if not updating after eventbus event

Tags: vue.js, dom, event-bus

Hi I'm having problems with a v-if that's not updating after receiving an eventbus event. This is my code :

```html
<template>
  <div class="main">
      <button  v-if="inCreationMode()">
        Make a new snippet
      </button>
      <button v-if="mode ==='edit'">Push edits</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      mode: "creation",
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.emitter.on("editSnippet", snippet => function(snippet){
      this.mode = "edit";
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

I tried replacing the v-if conditions by functions :

```js
    <template>
      <div class="main">
          <button  v-if="inCreationMode()">
            Make a new snippet
          </button>
          <button v-if="inEditMode()">Push edits</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          mode: "creation",
        };
      },
      created() {
        this.emitter.on("editSnippet", snippet => function(snippet){
          this.mode = "edit";
        });
      },
      methods:{
      inCreationMode() {
      return this.mode === "creation";
        },
       inEditMode(){
          return this.mode ==="edit";
         }
      }
    };
    </script>
```

I tried using this.$forceUpdate() as well.
Does anyone know a solution to this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How have you defined `this.emitter`?

Comment: It is just an even bus declared in the main .ts

Comment: As `new Vue()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see many problems here, that could all be part of the reason why it's not working. Given that you have defined your emitter to be `new Vue()`, and added that to the Vue prototype correctly and that the component that emits the event does it by `this.emitter.emit('editSnippet')`. You have to:

Replace

`this.emitter.on("editSnippet", snippet => function(snippet){ this.mode = "edit"; });`

with

`this.emitter.on("editSnippet", () => { this.mode = "edit";});`

Reasons:

1. You have to use an arrow function, otherwise `this` will not reference your component.
2. Your callback should be a function that "does something", not one that returns a function (that won't be called)

Further improvements (optional):

- Use computed props instead of methods as described in the other answer
- Cleanup the listener in `beforeUnmount` (or `beforeDestroy`) with `this.emitter.off...` . Actually not really optional, it is at least really bad code style to not do that

Answer (score 2):

You should use computed properties instead of methods in this case :

```js
   <template>
      <div class="main">
          <button @click="  inCreationMode() " v-if="inCreationMode">
            Make a new snippet
          </button>
          <button v-if="inEditMode">Push edits</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          mode: "creation",
        };
      },
      created() {
        this.emitter.on("editSnippet", snippet => function(snippet){
          this.mode = "edit";
        });
      },
      computed:{
      inCreationMode() {
      return this.mode === "creation";
        },
       inEditMode(){
          return this.mode ==="edit";
         }
      }
    };
    </script>
```

Note : remove the `()` from the `v-if` value